# Combinatorial perumutations in a time series using R

Tags: r, time-series, permutation, combinatorics

Imagine a time series experiment where each of the 3 time points (`A`, `B`, `C`) was replicated 3 times:

```
A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3
```

We would like to concatenate the data (generating a time series of 3 cycles: ABC,ABC,ABC) in all the possible permutations (using different time-point replicate each time). Here for example a few realizations:

```
A1, B1, C1,  A1, B1, C2, A1, B1, C3
A1, B2, C1,  A1, B2, C2, A1, B2, C3
A1, B3, C1,  A1, B3, C2, A1, B3, C3
```

Could anyone kindly suggest an R script to carry this task? Thanks in advance, Eran

Comment: May be you can try with `?expand.grid`

Answer (score 0):

using expand grid:

```
expand.grid(A = c("A1","A2","A3"), B = c("B1","B2","B3"), C = c("C1","C2","C3"))
```

returns

```
    A  B  C
1  A1 B1 C1
2  A2 B1 C1
3  A3 B1 C1
...
23 A2 B2 C3
24 A3 B2 C3
25 A1 B3 C3
26 A2 B3 C3
27 A3 B3 C3
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments below, there is a more subtle trick to this problem.

I'm fairly certain there is a more efficient way to do this, but I can't seem to think of a way beyond just testing all permutations:

```
library(gtools)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(expand.grid(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(1,2,3), C = c(1,2,3)))

perm <- data.frame(permutations(nrow(dt),3,1:nrow(dt)))
```

perm is a data frame with all possible permutations of rows.

We can now create a list, with each element being a combination:

```
mylist <- apply(perm,1,function(x,y){y[as.numeric(x)]},dt)
```

We can then test to see which list elements have *every column with three unique values*

```
mylist[as.logical(lapply(mylist,function(x){all(lapply(x,function(y){length(unique(y))}) == 3)}))]
```

This is a doozy of a formula, but it does the job. It returns a list of 3x3 data frames that meet the conditions above.

**EDIT 2:** nvm, Even simpler:

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)

dt <- data.table(permutations(n = 3, r = 3, v = 1:3))
perm <- data.frame(permutations(nrow(dt),3,1:nrow(dt), repeats.allowed = T))
mylist <- apply(perm,1,function(x,y){y[as.numeric(x)]},dt)

mylist <- lapply(mylist,t)
mylist <- lapply(mylist,`colnames<-`,c("A","B","C"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems useful, but what we really after are unique combinations from the triplets above (e.g replicates is used only once), e.g.              A3 B1 C3 ;A1 B2 C1 ;A2 B3 C2

Comment: @Eran would A1,B1,C1 ; A2,B2,C2 ; A3,B3,C3 also be a pattern?

Comment: thanks you so much, this is exactly what we needed! I'm totally grateful!